# Openshift - Edit secret from cli

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

For security reasons, I need to renew the password field of a Secret in Openshift every 30 days, so my idea is to create a cronjob and execute a ocp command to remove the password field from that Secret, so after this, the password field is autogenerated with a new password.
So I'm trying to edit a field from a Secret using the patch command but without success.
This is what the help command shows regarding patch:
[image: patch help]

and I tried the patch command like this:

`oc patch secret test-secret -p '{"data":{"password":}}'`

or

`oc patch secret test-secret -p $'data:\n password: '`

but I see this kind of errors:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "password:" not found
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "'" not found
```

Does anyone knows how to use the patch command to update the field of a ocp Secret?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oc patch secret test-secret -p '{"data":{"password": ""}}'
```

- empty double quotes in place value for password will work.

Comment: I tried that but this error is shown: error: unable to parse "'{data:{password:": yaml: found unexpected end of stream.

Comment: Trust the password field is there in the secret which you want patch.  Also the one which you had pasted in latest one is not proper

Comment: My problem was that I was using cmder to enter the ocp commands, after using git bash then the command works, thanks!